# Enforcing integers for declared inputs is not possible

Tags: openmdao

I try to declare an input with default integers but it does not seem possible. Am I making a mistake or is float enforced in the openmdao core.

Here are the code snippets I tried;

Expected output something like : array([1, 1, 1])

Received output : [1. 1. 1.]

```
from openmdao.api import ExplicitComponent,  Problem, IndepVarComp
import numpy as np

class CompAddWithArrayIndices(ExplicitComponent):
    """Component for tests for declaring with array val and array indices."""
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x_a', val=np.ones(6,dtype=int))
        self.add_input('x_b', val=[1]*5)
        self.add_output('y')

p = Problem(model=CompAddWithArrayIndices())
p.setup()
p.run_model()

print(p['x_a'])        
print(p['x_b'])   
#%%
from openmdao.api import ExplicitComponent,  Problem, IndepVarComp
import numpy as np

class CompAddWithArrayIndices(ExplicitComponent):
    """Component for tests for declaring with array val and array indices."""
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x_a', val=np.zeros(3,dtype=int))
        self.add_output('y')

prob = Problem()
ivc=IndepVarComp()
prob.model.add_subsystem('ivc', ivc,promotes=['*'])
ivc.add_output('x_a', val=np.ones(3,dtype=int))

prob.model.add_subsystem('comp1', CompAddWithArrayIndices(),promotes=['*'])

prob.setup()
prob.run_model()

print(prob['x_a'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables added via `add_inputs` or `add_outputs` will be converted to floats or float arrays.  If you want a variable to be an int or any other discrete type, you must use `add_discrete_input` and `add_discrete_output`.  Such variables will be passed between systems based on connection information, but no attempt will be made to compute their derivatives.

Discrete variable support was added in OpenMDAO v2.5 as an experimemental feature (its still being developed). There commit id 709401e535cf6933215abd942d4b4d49dbf61b2b on the master branch that promotion problem has been fixed.Make sure you're using a recent version of OpenMDAO from that commit or later

Comment: do these variables  also become not-accessible from problem level? because if I replace add_output and add_input to add_discrete_output and add_discrete_input in the lower example (in the code snippet above) i get an error 
KeyError: 'Variable name "x_a" not found.'

Comment: similarly in another code of mine, when i do the change from continuous to discrete input/output for 1 input/output array I get an error 

TypeError: compute() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given

I dont do any other code change

Comment: Maybe you are using a class, where the compute method was implemented with the old signature (`compute(inputs, outputs)`), and not the new one with the discrete inputs and outputs?

Comment: If a component contains discrete inputs or outputs, the longer form of compute that has two additional args (discrete_inputs and discrete_outputs), is called.